# Continuous function divisible by $(x-c)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

This is a very elementary question (which to my surprise hadn't already been answered on here): Given a continuous function $f: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(\frac{1}{3})=f(\frac{1}{2})=0$, is it true that $f(x)$ need be divisible by $(x-\frac{1}{3})(x-\frac{1}{2})$?

The motivation behind asking this question comes from exercise 7.4.9. (Dummit and Foote) which asks the reader to prove the set of all such functions form an ideal.

Comment: Divisible in the ring of continuous functions, or in the ring of all functions?

Comment: @aschepler Such a simple answer...but also so useful. Thank you! (And to add to my initial post: I'm looking to find a way as to define a generator for such an ideal of functions. With your comment, I'm now considering the set $((x-\frac{1}{3})(x-\frac{1}{2}))^k$ given any $k\in\mathbb{N}$...surely this is a step in a right direction?)

Comment: Reads to me like you actually want to consider polynomials or power series, in which case you are golden!

Comment: It's not hard to prove the set is an ideal directly from the definition, no matter what the ring. But finding generators for it again depends on what the larger ring is, and might be simple or tricky.

Comment: "number theory" is not an appropriate tag here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You’re right, my bad. I’ll change that. Thanks for point that out.

Comment: @aschepler divisible specifically with continuous functions.

Comment: In the ring of continuous functions, I'm not sure if the ideal is even countably generated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean divisibility in the ring of continuous functions. The answer is no, e.g. we could have $f(x) = \sqrt{|(x - \frac{1}{3})(x - \frac{1}{2})|}$. Then $\frac{f(x)}{(x - \frac{1}{3})(x - \frac{1}{2})}$ approaches $\infty$ as $x$ approaches either $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ so cannot extend to a continuous function on $[0, 1]$.

As aschepler says in the comments you don't need to know anything like this to prove that this set of continuous functions is an ideal, just apply the definition directly, or try to find a ring homomorphism such that this is the kernel.